# Defining MySQL connection in Slim Framework?

Tags: php, slim

I am hearing great things about Slim Framework- and it seems easy. Except none of the tutorials address where to put the MySQL info.

I see things like  `$dbCon = getConnection();`

But where do I define the username/pw/db/host etc?

Comment: slim doesn't come with a database connection to my knowledge.

Comment: Slim does not have database access but you can use any of the 'orm's with it. [Here as an example of using PHPactiveRecord' with it.](http://silentworks.co.uk/blog/development/using-phpactiverecord-with-slim-framework.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function in your file (e.g. index.php)

```
    function getConnection() {
    $dbhost="yourdbhost";
    $dbuser="yourdbuser";
    $dbpass="yourdbpass";
    $dbname="yourdb";
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;
    }
```

Comment: I don't like this approach personally because you end up with credentials in your source code. I would move the credentials to a local config file outside the web root thats ignored by your source control.

Comment: I agree with @ForrestLyman, database credentials have nothing to do in there.

Comment: this approach is not the best, there should be a .env file i guess

Answer (score 9):

First thing first lets open src/settings.php file and configure database connection details to the settings array as shown below.

```
<?php
return [
  'settings' => [
      'displayErrorDetails' => true, // set to false in production

      // Renderer settings
      ....
      ....    

      // Monolog settings
      ....
      ....

      // Database connection settings
      "db" => [
          "host" => "localhost",
          "dbname" => "slim3",
          "user" => "root",
          "pass" => "xxxxx"
      ],
   ],
];
```

There are many database libraries available for PHP, but this example uses PDO. Now open your src/dependencies.php file and configure database library as shown below. you can use your own libraries by adapting the example.

```
// DIC configuration
$container = $app->getContainer();

...
...
...

// PDO database library
$container['db'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['db'];
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $settings['host'] . ";dbname=" . $settings['dbname'],
        $settings['user'], $settings['pass']);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $pdo;
};
```

via: https://arjunphp.com/configure-load-database-slim-framework-3/

Answer (score 5):

Its best to keep these credentials in a local configuration file. I add a configs folder outside the web root and add a local.php configuration file to that.

```
....
/configs
    local.php
/public
/vendor
....
```

You can configure anything you like, but here's the DB:

```
<?php
// configs/local.php
return array(
    'db' => ['user' => 'root', 'password' => 'root']
);
```

Then include the file in your app and create the connection:

```
// public/index.php
$config = include(__DIR__ . '/../configs/local.php');
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", $config['db']['user'], $config['db']['password'] );

$app->get('/', function () use ($app, $db) {
    // do something with your db connection
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had great success with this MVC pattern where you store the credentials in a `config.php` file which gets loaded on every instance of a model: https://github.com/revuls/SlimMVC

Answer (score 2):

You can configure PDO in an external class:

```
 class Connection
    {
        protected $db;
        public function Connection()
        {
        $conn = NULL;
            try{
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=YOUR_HOST;dbname=DB_NAME;charset=utf8;collation=utf8_unicode_ci", "USER_DB", "PASS_DB");
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }   
            $this->db = $conn;
        }

        public function getConnection()
        {
            return $this->db;
        }
    }
```

Then in Slim (Php object oriented):

```
  <?php

   class Proxy
   {
    require_once 'Connection.php';

    // init Slim

    private $conn = NULL;

    // Api Rest code...


    # getConnection
    public function getConnection(){
        if(is_null($this->conn)){
            $this->conn = new Connection();
        }
        return $this->conn->getConnection();
    }
```

Or Php no OO:

```
  <?php

    require_once 'Connection.php';

    // init Slim

    $conn = NULL;

    // Api Rest code...


    # getConnection
    function getConnection(){
        global $conn;
        if(is_null($conn)){
            $conn = new Connection();
        }
        return $conn->getConnection();
    }
```